# setTimeout is precise on Linux but not on Windows?

Tags: node.js, timer, settimeout

I have a simple setTimeout usage:

```js
var oldDate = new Date().getTime();

setInterval(function(){
    var newDate = new Date().getTime();

    console.log(newDate - oldDate, 'ms');

    oldDate = newDate;
}, 7);
```

This prints on a **Linux** system with Node(v10.15.2):

```
8 'ms'
6 'ms'
8 'ms'
7 'ms'
8 'ms'
8 'ms'
```

But on a **Windows** system with Node(v10.15.1):

```
21 'ms'
22 'ms'
20 'ms'
20 'ms'
17 'ms'
23 'ms'
18 'ms'
20 'ms'
22 'ms'
17 'ms'
17 'ms'
22 'ms'
19 'ms'
20 'ms'
23 'ms'
19 'ms'
30 'ms'
```

It is an absolute mess and runs very randomly.

I need a precise and non-blocking timer. In linux it works like a charm, but I'm curious, why is it so bad in windows?

Thanks!

Comment: Side note: The simpler, more efficient version of `new Date().getTime()` is `Date.now()`.

Comment: There is no such thing as a precise, pre-emptive timer in Javascript.  Timer callbacks are event-based.  When the timer fires, it inserts an event in the event queue.  That event will run when it gets a turn, when other events that came before it are done processing.  That may or may not be close to the allotted time for the timer.

Comment: This seems a bit like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need it to be more precise than it is above?

Comment: Actually I'm making a gameserver which needs to run 60fps stable so I need a stable timer :) @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the timer subsystem for precise timing.

It's important to understand that even on Linux, it will only be "precise" provided your Node.js instance's main thread is never busy doing something else, like handling I/O completions or running some of your JavaScript logic. There's only one main thread in a Node.js program (you can have others via [`Worker`](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html)), which handles I/O completion callbacks and anything else your code does (unless it's on a worker thread). `setTimeout`/`setInterval` schedule normal tasks in the task queue, which also holds other tasks (such as, again, I/O completions).

If you really need timing that precise, you'll probably need to at least move it to a worker thread, and even then it may not be precise. If not, you might get closer with `setImmediate` loops. If that isn't close enough, you may need to busy-wait in the worker (which will peg a CPU core, but at least not the main thread).